# How to prove the Riemann Zeta fuction tends to infinity when $x$ tends to $1$

Tags: limits, analysis, uniform-convergence

The Riemann Zeta Function is convergent over the interval $(1,\infty)$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$ tends to infinity when $x\rightarrow 1^ {+} $, it seems one can feel it is right because the when $x=1$ the function is infinite and it is monotonely decreasing over the interval $(1,\infty)$.

But since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$ is not uniformly convergent at the interval $(1,1+\delta)$, so I can't simply exchange the limit order as follows:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$, so how can I compute this: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show that for every $M \in \Bbb R_{>0}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\zeta(x) > M$ for all $x \in (1, 1+\delta)$.

---

Assume that such an $M$ is given. As $\sum 1/n$ diverges, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{1}{n} > 2M.$$

Also, note that for each $n \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$, we have a $\delta_n > 0$ such that
$$\dfrac{1}{2n} < \dfrac{1}{n^x} , \qquad (*)$$
for all $x \in (1, 1+\delta_n).$
(This is because $n^x \to n$ as $x\to1^+$.)

By choosing $\delta = \min\{\delta_n \mid n \in \{1, \ldots, N\}\}$, we see that $(*)$ holds for all $x \in (1, 1 + \delta)$ and for all $n\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$.

Thus, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{1}{n^x} &> \sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{1}{2n}\\
&> \dfrac{1}{2}(2M)\\
&= M,
\end{align}
for all $x \in (1, 1 + \delta)$.

This gives us that
\begin{align}
\zeta(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^x}\\
&>\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{n^x}\\
&> M,
\end{align}
for all $x \in (1, 1 + \delta)$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can bound the sum by an integral that goes to infinity as $x\to1$.

Answer (score 0):

For each  $N$ we have $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{x}} \geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac 1 {n^{x}}$ and hence $\lim \inf_{x \to 1} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{x}} \geq \lim \inf_{x \to 1} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac 1 {n^{x}} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac 1 {n} $. Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you! Is it correct: let $N\rightarrow \infty$ and  $\lim \inf_{x \to 1} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{x}} \geq \lim \inf_{x \to 1} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac 1 {n^{x}} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n}$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  @red_rose

Comment: And since the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$ is monotone decreasing, could I use $\lim _{x \to 1} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{x}} \geq \lim _{x \to 1} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac 1 {n^{x}} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n}$ when $N\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I find that it is really a beautiful proof because it not only  prove the limit is infinite but also imply the $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}$ is higher or at least same order infinity to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$, it seems  they are likely to be same order infinity. Could you prove it